# Latex issue in OS X : "Undefined control sequence"

Tags: macos, latex

I have the following simple code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\begin{document}

Hello world !


\end{document}
```

I am getting the following message while compiling in my Mac OS X (I'm using MacOS Sierra 10.12.5 (16F73)).

```
LaTeX2e <2016/03/31>
Babel <3.9r> and hyphenation patterns for 83 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size12.clo)) (./test.aux
! Undefined control sequence.
l.3 \abx@aux@sortscheme
                       {nyt}
```

What's going wrong? There's no issue with the same code in the Linux OS.

Do I need to install some package or update/upgrade install `MacTex`?

Comment: Delete any of the auxiliary files in your working folder, especially `test.aux`, and retry compiling.

Comment: @Werner Do you want to write an answer? Or is there a duplicate around here?